# How to configure the compiler of VS 2012 to change a basic data type size?

Tags: c++, int, size

How to configure the compiler of VS 2012 to change the type of int variable to become 2 byte instead of  4 bytes?
i have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{   
    typedef __int16 int16_t;
    int16_t x=5;
    std::cout<<"Size of integer number= "<<sizeof(x)<<" Bytes\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Is this what the compiler configuration mean?
I think the answer of my question is not a piece of code , it is about changing some setting in VS am i right?

Comment: i wrote the above code and by printing the size of the integer variable x, it was 2 bytes.is that the compiler configuration?

Comment: __int16 by it's name reflect that it's 2 bytes. your program is not doing much useful. you should check MSDN help for VS configurations.

Comment: Pretty sure Windows assumes [ILP32 data model](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/datatypesize64.htm) in which case int will always be 4 bytes - although it's not guaranteed by the standard in any case. For you, you almost definitely need to stick to `int16_t` (from `stdint.h` header, your `typedef` is redundant).

Comment: When someone told you that the C++ data type `int` doesn't have to be 32 bits, it could be 16 bits, they didn't mean that this is possible with the C++ compiler in Visual Studio.  Other companies besides Microsoft make C++ compilers (and even Microsoft has made C++ compilers for several *different* platforms, such as for DOS, for Windows CE, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, and if you could you would break compatibility with every library you are using, so the result wouldn't work anyway.

Use the 16-bit compiler, if they still ship it, or `int16_t`.